# Recursive routine in a method

Tags: ruby, recursion, subroutine, ruby-1.9.3

Often, I have a recursive routine within a method that is only called by that method or within the recursive routine itself:

```
def foo
  ...
  bar
  ...
end

def bar
  ...
  bar
  ...
end
```

But since `bar` is not used anywhere else, I do not want to define it as a method but somehow put it inside the method that calls it like this:

```
def foo
  ...
  bar {# some way to mark the recursive routine
    ...
    bar # some way to call the recursive routine
    ...
  }
  ...
end
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easy with a lambda/proc:

```
def foo(n)
  fact = lambda do |i|
    i.zero? ? 1 : i * fact.call(i-1)
  end
  fact.call(n)
end

foo(4) # => 24
```

You can also use a protected or private method.

If performance is a real concern, creating an object (the lambda) each time will be slower, and calling a lambda is also slower, closure and all. My [`fruity`](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity) gem gives me [a 3.3x slowdown](http://pastie.org/3612821) on this trivial example; the penalty should be much less for cases that actually do something more involved. Just be sure that performance really is an issue; you know what they say about premature optimization...

Comment: Iiiiiinteresting. I didn't think this would work due to `fact` not yet being assigned at the time the lambda was created, but it does work (at least in 1.9.2). +1

Comment: Ruby's parser goes strictly left to right, so as soon as `fact =` is parsed, `fact` is recognized as a local variable.

Comment: I thought that answers will be along this line (although without clear view on how exactly it will be). How does this do performance-wise? Does it dramatically slow down?

Comment: @sawa The performance of this is excellent, not that you should worry too much about it. Blocks are a huge part of Ruby, and that's all this is (a Proc or Lambda is just a block wrapped in an object).

Comment: I just downloaded your `fruity` and am playing around with it. It is amazing.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're trying to do functional programming in an object-oriented language. You might be better served by creating a small class with a single responsibility:

```
class Routiner
  def foo(*args)
    # occasionally...
    do_work(some_data)
  end
protected
  def do_work(data)
    # ...work work work
    do_work(more_data) if some_condition
  end
end

Routiner.new.foo('bar', 'baz', 'bat')
```

Answer (score 0):

@coreyward 's answer is good, but there's another trick you could use to limit the scope of the recursive function using lambda.

```
def foo
  ...
  bar = lambda do |arg|
    ...
    bar.call(...)
    ...
  end

  bar.call(...)
  ...
end
```

Since bar is lexically scoped within foo, no other method can see it or call it, but the lambda which bar refers to can see bar since it closes over the lexical scope where it's defined.